# How do I check for empty attr() in jquery?

Tags: jquery, each, attr

I have a few divs that are created using PHP. The anchor within the div always has a HREF, even if it is blank. Basically, I am trying to detect if the HREF is blank. If it has content, do nothing, if it's blank, strip the text out, delete the anchor, them put the text back in.

Here is the div:

```
<div class="title"> 
    <a class="article" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a> 
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //required for $ to work in Wordpress

    $(".article").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href') !== undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            var linkTitle = $(this).html();
            $(this).parent().empty().html(linkTitle);
        }                               
    });    
//-->
});
```

Comment: where is article in the html my mistake i see it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check for an empty `href` attribute and "unwrap" those links using [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) like this:

```
$(".article[href='']").replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ErEw2/).

Comment: I like how this removes the need for a conditional branch

Comment: It works in your link, but when I put it in my code, I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: @Jared - I sounds like you copied some weird ascii character looking like a space in there...try deleting the spacing around anything you copied.

Comment: I copy/pasted it in notepad to try and get rid of illegal chars, seems to work now, thanks!. But I am not sure I understand WHY this code works? Does replaceWith() have some ability that automatically checks for attributes, and if it doesn't find any, it executes its function?

Comment: @Jared - The `[href='']` is what's checking for the empty `href` attribute...then the `.replaceWith()` is only working on *those* anchors, make sense?

Answer (score 18):

You can simply test the attribute as a boolean instead of testing it against `undefined`:

```
if ($(this).attr('href')) {
  // href is not blank
} else {
  // href is blank
}
```

Comment: `this.href` is much easier ;)

Comment: doesn't that just check if there is an href attr(), not if it is blank?

Comment: @Nick I sometimes forget that there's this archaic "JavaScript" thing sitting below jQuery :p

Comment: @Jared No, it will return the value of the attribute or `undefined` if it doesn't exist. In JavaScript, `""` (an empty string) is equivalent to boolean false.  `attr()` will evaluate to `false` if the attribute doesn't exist or is empty.

Comment: note that IE8 will also return an empty string if the href doesn't exist.  The if expression is still valid, but does try href="" and no href as equivalent on IE.

Answer (score 1):

To simply get rid of the 'href' attribute:

```
$("#myLink[href='']").removeAttr('href');
```

For multiple targeting, for example the 'style' attribute:

```
$("#myDiv td, a, p, table, nav, header[style='']").removeAttr('style');
```

This way, you'll only get rid of the Attribute when it's empty instead of deleting the whole element itself.

A full code example would be:

```
$('#myDiv table, tr, td, a, p').each(function() { 
if ($(this).attr('style') == '') { 
    $(this).removeAttr('style'); 
} 
})
```